# How to check if the method modernizer.mq is supported?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created a navigation with hover effect with  the Modernizer.mq method:

```
$('ul#mainNav > li').hover(function() {
    if(Modernizr.mq('(min-width: 701px)'))
    {
```

Since I want a hover effect for the navigation when width is larger then 700px and a click-mobile like navigation when the width is less then 700px.

I used the above code instead of

```
$('ul#mainNav > li').hover(function() {
    if($( window ).width()> 701)
    {
```

because `$( window ).width()` is different from my media-queries.

For IE < 8 I use [respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond) to get my mediq-queries working. However, I noticed that my hover does not work anymore because the method Modernizr.mq is not working. Is there a way to find out if the method Modernizr.mq is supported?

Something like:

```
var mqWorks = checkIfMqWorks();

$('ul#mainNav > li').hover(function() {
   if(mqWorks){
       if(Modernizr.mq('(min-width: 701px)'))
       {...}
       } else {
           if($( window ).width()> 701)
            {...}
       }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the typeof contruct in an if then statement.

Live Example http://codepen.io/larryjoelane/pen/NxZKWr

JavaScript:

```
//test conditions
var modernizrLoaded = typeof Modernizr === "object";

var modernizrMQLoaded =  typeof Modernizr.mq === "function";

var modernizrMinWidth = Modernizr.mq('(min-width: 10px)');


//debugging tests
console.log(modernizrLoaded);
console.log(modernizrMQLoaded);
console.log(modernizrMinWidth);


//if Modernizr is object that is loaded. It contains an mq function and the test function call for mq returns true
if (modernizrLoaded && modernizrMQLoaded && modernizrMinWidth) {

  console.log("Modernizr is a function and the mq function call returns true.");

} else {

  console.log("false")

}
```

You could then create a function to call or just place your code in the if block to run if the conditions are met and place your code for when the conditions are not met in the else block.

Comment: so if this condition is true, then modernizr.mq works?

Comment: @adam Well it means that the mq function of exists at least.

Comment: @adam See my update I forgot to add double quotes to function.

Comment: maybe one could include a second if statement in the braces asking`if(Modernizr.mq('(min-width: 10px)') or Modernizr.mq('(max-width: 10px)') )' if this returns true, then the function should work - would that be possible?

Comment: @Adam You could do something like that, I am testing another condition for my answer that I didn't take into account. I will have an update in a minute.

Comment: @Adam I added an additional check to see if modernizer is loaded

Comment: But even if Modernizr.mq is loaded, it simply might not work and I need to include  a check like mentioned in my last comment right? For example in IE8.

Comment: @Adam let me try that check and I will get right back to you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104037/discussion-between-larry-lane-and-adam).